# How to turn off charging while SCR is latching?

Tags: high-voltage, scr

So I'm trying to make a CDI for my old motorcycle that can be controlled using Arduino, after a bit of research (mainly Googling) and prototyping I come up with this design, this design has been tested but I want to improve two things:

1. This design needs the micro controller to turn off the UC3845 (U1) by pulling the COMP pin to GND before turning the triggering the SCR (Q2) to prevent it from being stuck on its ON state, I want to simplify this process, is there a way to only allow U1 to be ON only when Q2 is in its OFF so the MCU only need to trigger 1 pin?
2. The D5 is a new addition that I haven't tested yet (I'm waiting on parts to arrive) the idea is to have an indicator whether the capacitor (C6) still have charge in it, is there a safer way to do this? I don't want the LED to cause a spark to be generated at the coil when I don't want it.

[image: CDI Module Diagram]

My background is a software engineer so I don't know all the technical terms that electrical engineers are familiar with, but I'm willing to learn if you explain it to me or point me to the right resources. The last thing is I don't have an oscilloscope.

Comment: Left side of C1 & C5 is not connected (I assume they should be grounded).

Comment: You're right it's should be grounded, i will update the it

Comment: The placement of C6 is suspicious, and the purpose of D2 is unclear. C6 blocks DC, and the output at J1 can never be more than 0.7V due to D2. Surely you want to take the output across C6? With D2 in place, the SCR can't discharge C6, and the LED can't show the presence of charge on C6.

Comment: The only untested changes is the addition of the LED (and the ballast resistor for it), other than that the circuit is tested and able to deliver enough voltage to the ignition coil to produce spark.

The D2 is mainly used to charge C6 when U1 is ON, I have an old prototype that still work using this design i'll try to record it and post it here.

I think the design is confusing because the ignition coil is on the diagram, i will update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical holding current of that SCR is about 7 mA. A NPN transistor can detect that current with a current sense resistor of 120 Ohm, and with 2 diodes in parallel, voltage drop will not be more than 2 V.

Regarding the LED, it will demand current at high voltage, this will be detrimental for charging capacitor. I suggest to detect with another transistor and power the LED from 12 V.

See simulation above with a 120 V supply, main discharge current will flow through diodes, and bellow 7 mA, through the 120 Ohm resistor. S2 will simulate the SCR.

[image]

Comment: I do not recognize some of these symbols such as V1, V2, V3, S1, S2 and A1, can you explain what those symbols are ?

Comment: After a bit of Googling again, I think i understand this circuit but let me try to explain what i think is going on and you can correct me if i'm wrong.

1. The two diodes (D1, D2) in series are there to create a voltage different between the Base of Q1 and its Emitter.
2. The R3 is just current limiting resistor to protect the BJT.
3. The R2 is there to create a higher resistance path for the current so enough current flow through Q1's Base pin.

Comment: @collin power: R2 will drop about 0.7 V when current is 7 mA, so Q1 will get enough base to emitter voltage to switch on and block the power supply. If D1 & D2 not exist, the voltage through R2 will be very high at the initial moment of discharging C1. These 2 diodes will limit the voltage to about 2 V.  Regarding R3: right , it will limit Q1 base current in high current condition (voltage drop = 2V). R4 is not necessary, only for simulation.

Comment: I kinda understand what you're saying, but let me ask a few thing to strengthen my understanding
1. The diodes is acting as a voltage clamp to protect Q1 correct ? if so can i use Zener in reverse (kathode on R3 and anode on GND) so i only need 1 diode and i can easily order part the voltage clamping that the Q1 need ?
2. What is the difference between voltage drop cause by R2 and D1+D2 ? what happen if i remove R2 but keep everything else the same ?

Comment: @collin power: If you know the voltage of charged capacitor and coil resistance, you can estimate the current peak when SCR is switched on. Probably is more than 1 A, for a short time. So you need to find a zener that supports that current peak (the SCR can live up to 12 A RMS), that will be more expensive than 2 rectifiers. A diode is not a linear load (google I/V relation), so you need R2 to fix the current to be detected at low value. With a zener and no R2 wil happen the same, Q1 will switch on with an unknown current.

Comment: let me try to re-explain it again to make sure i get it right.
1. Since the SCR will leak some current we uses R2 as load (effectively pull-down resistor ?) so only sufficient enough current can trigger the Q1, which should only happen when S2 is triggered.
2. The diodes is mainly use to clamp the voltage to protect Q1 from over voltage.
CMIIW

Does the diode also "protect" R2 at high voltage by providing the least resistance path for the current ?

Comment: @colling power: right, also if no diodes to clamp, the current through the coil and R2 will be reduced very much.

Comment: Thank you @Bravale, this design work for me, but one thing i change is to make it safer for the low voltage component Q1 is now turning on an optocoupler to isolate the high voltage side of the pcb to the rest.

Comment: i have another question, on my original schema i have an adjustable voltage divider (RV1), im thinking of connecting the same voltage divider to a mosfet to turn on an LED to indicate that the capacitor still have charge. My thinking is since mosfet don't draw current when its already "ON" the only current draw from the capacitor will we the existing voltage divider that is necessary for the feedback this way i don't add additional load on the capacitor, what do you think ?

Comment: @collin power: the high impendace of the gate should not be a problem. I suggest to protect again high voltage this point, with a zener (a little below max. Vgs voltage) and a high value resistor (no influence to voltage divider in case zener is on).